# How to get the previous value in a list of strings in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I'm trying to implement a previous and next buttons.

I have a list of string called **list1** which is filled with whatever is a user has inputted from a textbox. I can't access the previous (not the last) string in the list. IndexOf method isn't useful as I don't know what user will input.

```
private void previousBtn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    getList();
    int min = 0;
    int max = list1.Count;
    if(max==min)
    {
        previousBtn.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        int temp =list.Count-1;
        //how do I get my string if I know the element index from the previous line?
        //textbox1.Text = thatPreviousString; 
    }
}
```

Sorry, it should be easy but I can't figure it out. How can I actully get my previous string in the list if the value is kind of unknown to me, so I can't just use find() and indexOf. 
MSDN shows that there is a property called **Item** but there is no proper tutorial or code bit that shows how to use it.

**UPDATE:** 
Let's say the user has typed "www.google.com", "www.facebook.com", "twitter.com" and then "www.yahoo.com". This urls are saved in list1. The last one was "www.yahoo.com", I can get it by calling Last(). The user can press the previous button anytime, so I can't specify the number of elements in list1, it's growing dynamically. I can only get the number of elements by calling

```
list1.Count and the last index by calling list1[list1.Count-1]
```

Now I know the number of indexes and elements, so how do I get the previous string, e.g. "www.twitter.com", if I can only say I can give you the index, give my string back?

By the way, ElementAs is only for arrays, doesn't work for lists.

Comment: are you getting an error or the wrong data?  If an error, can you share what it says?

Comment: Not really sure about your question but you can  use [`List<T>.ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) to get an element at a particular index.

Comment: Can't you just get the item at the last index of the array, last - 1, last - 2, etc.?  If it's an actual `List<T>` then `.Last()`, etc.?

Comment: `Item` is the official name for the square bracket operator `[]` to be used through reflection and from other .NET languages.

Comment: @David, yep, I can access the last and the first string with *Last()* and *First()* but I need the one before the last. So I need the actual string, not an index of the previous element

Comment: @Messerschmitt: The one before the last would be the item at the last - 1 index.  With that you can *get* the actual string at that index.

Comment: What is the list of strings called?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, in this case it's called **list1**.

Comment: @Messerschmitt If list1 is a list of strings, why are you trying to assign an element from it to an int variable, `temp`?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: You could also use the `LinkedList<T>` class and would not have to reinvent the wheel. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

> > how do I get my string if I know the element index from the previous line?

```
int prevIndex; // element index from the previous line that you know
string temp = list1[prevIndex - 1];
```

Comment: Ah, well done. You managed to decode what the OP was asking for. Have an upvote for your psychic powers! :)

Comment: Hm, I can assign prevIndex to find the last index of the list by listH.Count-1, I can get the previous index as you've showed but how do I get my string if I now know the index from the previous steps?

Comment: @Messerschmitt You get it by fixing the type of temp. If the line reads `string temp = list1[prevIndex - 1];`, then temp will hold that previous string.

Comment: @DavidArno lol thanks, it was in a comment in the code all along!

Comment: Oh, thanks @Weston. I've mixed up your answer with *dasblinkenlight* as he proposed to use the last()-1 which promts an error that I can't assign strings to integers. Yours is working fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`string temp =list[list.Count-1];` will give you the last element in the list.

`string temp =list[list.Count-2];` will give you the previous element.

Remember, lists are 0-indexed, ie the first element is accessed via `[0]`, so the last element will be `[list size - 1]`.

So in your case `textbox1.Text = list[list.Count-2];` will write the previous string into the textbox.

However, that won't give you a proper previous functionality. Pressing previous again won't give you `list[list.Count-3]`. You could though have a `currentIndex` variable that you decrement whenever previous is pressed for example and do `textbox1.Text = list[currentIndex]`.

Comment: Thanks, @David but this just gives the int or index of the previous value and I need the actual string stored at that index. How I can I get that one?

Comment: @Messerschmitt Then you need to clarify your code. You are only showing one list: list1. You are determining whether to show the previous button based on that list. What other list do you have? I have updated the answer to refer to a generic `list` variable as I don't know your string list's name.

Comment: Sorry @David, it worked fine, I just mixed up yours and weston's solution with *dasblinkenlight*. Need to do some changes to the code, so it works for all cases. Thanks for pointing *currentIndex*, will try with that now and sorry for disappointment!